# calculate an integration by using residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)\left[\,{\ln^{2}\left(x\right) + \pi^{2}}\,\right]}
$$
Calculate the following integration using the residue theorem.

Comment: Your picture does not match your $\LaTeX$ input.  With which problem do you want help?

Answer (score 5):

Sub $x=e^y$ to get that

$$I = \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{\cosh{y}\: (y^2+\pi^2)}$$

We may evaluate using the residue theorem by considering the contour integral

$$\frac12 \oint_C \frac{dz}{\cosh{z}\: (z^2+\pi^2)}$$

where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ centered at the origin and closed in the upper half plane.  One may show that the integral over the circular arc vanishes in the limit as $R\to\infty$, so that the original integral $I$ is simply $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the poles of the integrand in the upper half plane.  As the poles are at $z_k=i (2 k+1)\pi/2$ and $z=i \pi$.  Then

$$I = i \pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{i [(-(2 k+1)^2 \pi^2/4+\pi^2]} + \frac{i \pi}{(-1) i 2 \pi}$$

or $$I=\frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2 k+1)^2-4} - \frac12$$

The sum is easily evaluated by partial fractions, i.e.,

$$\frac1{(2 k+1)^2-4} = \frac14 \left (\frac1{2 k-1}-\frac1{2 k+3} \right ) $$

so we get

$$I = \frac1{\pi} \left [-\left(-1-\frac13\right) + \left (1-\frac15\right)-\left(\frac13-\frac17\right)+\cdots \right ]-\frac12$$

or

$$I = \frac{2}{\pi}-\frac12$$

Comment: thanx Ron,but in this way you didn't identify the values ​​of the  residues.

Comment: @user119436: Need I have done so?  To want to evaluate the integral using residues, I assumed that you could perform that step.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{x} + \pi^{2}}}
=
\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}
{-\expo{-x}\dd x \over \pars{\expo{-2x} + 1}\pars{x^{2} + \pi^{2}}}
=
\half\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over \cosh\pars{x}\pars{x^{2} + \pi^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\,2\pi\ic\,{1 \over \cosh\pars{\ic\pi}\pars{\pi\ic + \pi\ic}}
+
\half\,2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\lim_{x \to x_{n}}
{x - x_{n} \over \cosh\pars{x}\pars{x^{2} + \pi^{2}}}
\\&\mbox{where}\qquad
x_{n} \equiv \pars{n + \half}\pi\ic\,,\quad n\ \in\ {\mathbb Z}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\bracks{\ln^{2}\pars{x} + \pi^{2}}}
=
-\,\half
+
\pi\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \underbrace{\sinh\pars{x_{n}}}_{\pars{-1}^{n}\ \ic}
\pars{x_{n}^{2} + \pi^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,\half + \pi\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \bracks{\pars{n + 1/2}\pi\ic}^{2} + \pi^{2}}
=
-\,\half + {1 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over -\pars{n + 1/2}^{2} + 1}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,\half - {1 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
{1 \over \pars{n - 1/2}\pars{n + 3/2}}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,\half - {1 \over 4\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n - 1/4}\pars{n + 3/4}}
+
{1 \over 4\pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n + 1/4}\pars{n + 5/4}}
\end{align}
The sums are evaluated with the identity
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{k + z_{0}}\pars{k + z_{1}}}
=
{\Psi\pars{z_{0}} - \Psi\pars{z_{1}} \over z_{0} - z_{1}}
$$
where $\Psi\pars{z}$ is the $\it\mbox{digamma function}$.

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \ln^{2}\pars{x} + \pi^{2}}=
> \int_{\infty}^{-\infty}{-\expo{-x}\dd x \over x^{2} + \pi^{2}}
> \quad\mbox{diverges !!!}
> $$